# Mobile marker's title on Google maps API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to allow the marker's title to be displayed on a mobile device?
For example:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: position,title: 'My title'});
```

I simply want the title to be displayed on a mobile device (I tested with iOS) when the user taps on the marker (which should be interpreted as a mouseover, right?).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `title` option is used for when you hover your mouse over the marker on the desktop.

If you want to show the name then you can try binding a click even to the marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    document.getElementById('some_element').textContent = marker.getTitle();
});
```

Or you could also try using an [infoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow)